# CircleCI version 2.1 - "Cannot find a definition for command named 'restore-cache'"

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm currently attempting to use the `commands` feature available in CircleCI version 2.1, so that I can reuse some common commands. I'm testing using the CLI command:

```
circleci config process ./.circleci/config.latest.yaml > ./.circleci/config.yml
```

But I recieve the following error:

```
Error: Error calling workflow: 'main'
Error calling job: 'build'
Error calling command: 'build_source'
Cannot find a definition for command named restore-cache
```

It seems that `restore-cache` works just fine in a straight-up version 2 config file, but when I try and process a 2.1 file using `process` it kicks up a fuss.

Below is an edited version of my `config.yaml` file which should hopefully be of some use. Please let me know if there is any additional information that would be useful.

```
version: 2.1

defaults: &defaults
  /**
   *  Unimportant stuff
   */

aliases:
  - &restore-root-cache
    keys:
      - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}
      - v1-deps

commands:
  build_source:
    description: 'Installs dependencies, then builds src, builds documentation, and runs tests'
    steps:
      - restore-cache: *restore-root-cache
      - other-commands...

jobs:
  build:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - build_source

workflows:
  version: 2.1
  main:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore: develop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is `restore_cache` (with an underscore), not `restore-cache` (with a dash) https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#restore_cache

It should work in commands.

Answer (score -1):

restore cache is a special step that needs to be under a job. Not another command.